# detect audio streaming error in phonegap

Tags: android, cordova, audio-streaming, cordova-2.7.0

I'm streaming from online with the address

```
http://83.170.109.107:8004
```

Code looks like

```
    var snd = new Media(add_list[parameter],onSuccess,onplayError,mediaStatus);
    snd.play();
function onSuccess() {
     console.log("start");
    }
function onplayError(err) {
    console.log("error occurred"+err.code);

}
function mediaStatus(code) {
    console.log(code);

}
```

This works perfectly when the stream exists on that address.But **onSuccess** never fired. **mediaStatus** method is working properly. Now I want to make it error proof. That means if there is no stream exists on an address, it will catch the error and show a message.

So I provided an fake address

```
 http://184.172.000.000:0000
```

Now methods are not fired. **onSuccess, onplayError & mediaStatus** all methods failed. In android LogCat is only showing

> 12-03 15:41:34.376: E/MediaPlayer(24895): Error (1,-110)

I tried to use  **try catch**, that's not working either. **Can anyone please tell me how can I detect if the stream does not exist? And why those methods are not working properly while streaming?**

Comment: Can you try using an actual valid address where a stream doesn't exist?  `184.172.000.000` won't generally parse as a valid IP address, and `0000` is not a valid port.  Try something like `http://example.com/no_stream_here`.

Comment: @Brad same result. Tried with 184.172.155.155:8322 which is fake, same result. And with example.com/no_stream_here and something similar it gives 12-04 09:57:06.164: E/MediaPlayer(8337): error (1, -2147483648)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess there is no answer for this. So here is what I did.
It's not a direct way rather a way around.

I used a function with interval which checks for a fixed amount of time and then fires to see if the app got any stream on the respective address. It it gets any valid stream than it continues and if it doesn't then it consider as the stream doesn't exist. Not a direct but working temporarily for me.